# Gradle com.android.support and com.google.android.gms library conflict

Tags: android, gradle

I'm working on a Firebase chat app inside my main project and I added Firebase dependencies to my build.gradle, but then I got this message after sync:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes.) Found versions 25.3.1, 25.0.0, 23.4.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 and com.android.support:palette-v7:25.0.0

on

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

and

> All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes.) Found versions 9.8.0, 10.2.6. Example include com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:9.8.0 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:10.2.6

on

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.6'
```

Here is my dependencies in **build.gradle** *(Module:app)*:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile files('lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.6'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


//Chat dependencies
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
compile 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your build.gradle file,
duplicate line of code found

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

remove one and try .